# Makefile example issue regarding dir variable

Tags: makefile

Hello I am a bit new to makefiles, i know the basics and thought I'd work through an example i found online. However i ran into something that doesn't seem right and i was hopping somone could help clear things up. The example can be found at the following link:
https://riptutorial.com/makefile/example/21376/building-from-different-source-folders-to-different-target-folders

My specific question is regarding the following line:

`SOURCEDIRS = $(foreach dir, $(DIRS), $(addprefix $(SOURCEDIR)/, $(dir)))`

I was wondering how the makefile could evaluate $(dir) when the dir variable was not assigned anywhere? is dir some sort of pre defined GNU Makefile variable or am i missing something?
Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, look up [`foreach`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Foreach-Function). The function iterates through `$(DIRS)`, assigning each word of it to `dir` in turn, and evaluating `$(addprefix $(SOURCEDIR)/, $(dir))`. This has the effect of prepending `$(SOURCEDIR)/` to each word in `$(DIRS)`.

Then look up [`addprefix`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#File-Name-Functions). This function can do all of the work by itself, so `foreach` is completely unnecessary in this example. This will suffice:

```
SOURCEDIRS = $(addprefix $(SOURCEDIR)/,$(DIRS))
```